# Azure Speech SDK on raspberry pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, arm, windowsiot, azure-speech

Is there a way to use the Speech SDK with C# on a raspberry pi (ARM or ARM64) using linux or windows IoT?
Preferably an .NET Core.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM64 is only supported for C++ and Java development. C# and .NET Core are only supported for x64. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk?tabs=linux):

> Currently, we only support Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04, Debian 9, Red
>   Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 8, and CentOS 8 on the following target
>   architectures:
>
> - x86 (Debian/Ubuntu), x64, ARM32 (Debian/Ubuntu), and ARM64 (Debian/Ubuntu) for C++ development
> - x64, ARM32 (Debian/Ubuntu), and ARM64 (Debian/Ubuntu) for Java
> - x64 for .NET Core and Python